# Nested inline if statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, nested, conditional-operator

In VB .Net it is possible to use inline `If` statements, like this

```
if a Then ret = "A" Else ret = "Not A"
```

I know it is also possible to nest these statements. I know this might not be good practice as readability drops down...

```
If a Then If b Then ret = "A & B" Else ret = "A & Not B" Else ret = "Not A"
```

which will be evaluated like this :

```
If a Then
    If b Then
        ret = "A & B"
    Else
        ret = "A & Not B"
    End If
Else
    ret = "Not A"
End If
```

Now if I remove the last `Else` statement, I get this :

```
If a Then If b Then ret = "A & B" Else ret = "A & Not B"
```

which is :

```
If a Then
    If b Then
        ret = "A & B"
    Else
        ret = "A & Not B"
    End If
End If
```

So I guess the compiler finds the `Else` and matches it to the last openend `If` in the line, which makes sense.
My question is : Is it possible to change the evaluation order ? By that I mean is it possible that the Else is matched with the first if ?

So it would look like this :

```
If a Then
    If b Then
        ret = "A & B"
    End If
Else
    ret = "Not A"
End If
```

But inlined (something like this, parenthesis added to understand what I mean) :

```
If a Then ( If b Then ret = "A & B" ) Else ret = "Not A"
```

I tried with parenthesis or adding a `End If` but it provokes syntax errors, and I couldn't find documentation for this.

I'm not stuck anywhere and I know this might not be a good prorgamming practice, but I just wanted to know (out of curiosity) if it was possible.

I know also I could switch the statements (i.e. test b before a), but let's say I can't (a is a List and must be tested for Nothing before b which would be the Count for example).

Comment: If you are confusing the compiler, imagine yourself trying to make sense of that 6 months down the road

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
ret = If(a, If(b, "A & B", "A & Not B"), "Not A")
```

Personally, I never understood the need to put everything in one line.

Comment: Problem with this is that both statements get evaluated ([From here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)).

Comment: That link says the opposite @MartinVerjans. Short circuiting means only the part that applies is evaluated.  the inner `If` will only execute when a is true otherwise it "jumps" to the false part

Comment: The If operator is different than the If statement though @MartinVerjans

Comment: @MartinVerjans [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx) behave differently than IF.

Comment: Is there any imports to do or reference to add ? Using VS 2012 Express and .Net 3.5, the compiler doesn't recognize it...

Comment: @MartinVerjans shouldn't be any import. What error do you get?

Comment: I a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531237/if-not-recognized-in-vb-net-3-5-vs2012)

Answer (score 2):

You may find that this is what you need:

```
If a And B Then

   ret = "A & B"

Else

   ret = "Not A"

End If
```

Or as a single line:

```
If A And B Then Ret = "A & B" Else RET = "Not A"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a simple console application with your final nested if statement and it worked fine

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a = False
    Dim b = True
    If a Then
        If b Then
            Console.WriteLine("A & B")
        End If
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("A & Not B")
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: I know this would work, I  am asking if it's possible to do that in an inline statement.