# if() not recognized in VB .Net 3.5 VS2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-3.5

I just asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530315/nested-inline-if-statement), where the answer proposed to use the `If()` function.

I tried in my Visual Studio, but it seems not present...

Here is a screenshot of the Intellisense :
[image]

It only shows me the classical If structure.

When I write it out completely

```
If(True, Debug.Write("A"), Debug.Write("B"))
```

I get a syntax error, saying :

> If must end by a corresponding End If

What am I missing here ?

.Net Framework 3.5

Visual Studio 2012 Express

The project is a Console Application and I tried also in Winforms...

Comment: The If operator is not the same as the If statement - `ret = If(True, "A", "B")`  The IF statement is to control program flow, the operator evaluates the condition(s) to return a value

Comment: `If True Then Debug.Write("A") Else Debug.Write("B")` is just as easy to type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The If() *operator* returns a value, try:

```
Debug.Write(If(True, "A", "B"))
```

Comment: Thanks. it's funny however that I can't just use it like that. I mean I can use a function without assigning it...

Comment: Plutonix and Hans (his edit to my post) point out that If() is an operator and not a VB statement - the rules are different.

Comment: @MartinVerjans - It's not a function, it's an operator.